# If a girl tells you "きらいじゃない" what does that really mean

Tags: english-to-japanese

If a girl tells you "きらいじゃない" what does that really mean. Is there a cultural meaning like shes just not interested in you?

Comment: This is a question for the human relation group I think. Whatever the language, some stuff do not change!

Comment: Could you confirm what she is talking about? About your shirt? Also, what is the complete sentence/dialog? For instance is it いや、きらいじゃないけど、… ?

Answer (score 4):

ない means "not" and じゃ is a colloquial form of では. きらいじゃない means "it is not that (I) dislike (you)".

What it *really* means depends on the context, but usually it just means "I don't dislike you (although I don't particularly interested in you, either)" It may imply another thing, typically when this is said by a [tsundere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere) character who cannot say "I like you."

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [litote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).

"I don't dislike you" is probably the most famous example.

This is not a Japanese specific thing, and the interpretation is totally up to you, inferring from context.